# SQL query works in SQL Server 2008 but doesn't work in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am working on an application and I have to retrieve some data from the database. I am using the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Context.ContextId, ContextName 
FROM Context
INNER JOIN RunInstance 
   ON Context.ContextId IN 
      (SELECT RunInstance.ContextId 
       FROM RunInstance 
       INNER JOIN ProcessInstance 
          ON RunInstance.RunInstanceId 
             IN (SELECT RunInstanceId FROM ProcessInstance 
                 WHERE RiskDate = '2010-08-20' ));
```

This query works perfectly in SQL Server 2008.

However, when I put it in my C# application it is not showing me any output.

My code:

```
string squery = @"SELECT DISTINCT Context.ContextId, ContextName FROM Context INNER JOIN RunInstance ON Context.ContextId IN 
    (Select RunInstance.ContextId From RunInstance 
    INNER JOIN ProcessInstance ON RunInstance.RunInstanceId 
    IN (SELECT RunInstanceId FROM ProcessInstance Where 
    RiskDate = '2010-08-20' )); ";

using(SqlConnection sqcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WMLON-Z8-SQL20,61433;Initial Catalog=statusdb;Integrated Security=True")){
    sqcon.Open();
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(squery,sqcon))
        using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()){
            while(reader.Read()){
                Console.WriteLine(reader[0]+"\t"+reader[1]);
            }
        }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem is?

Comment: Because you have a backtick (`) in the "using" line?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line?

Comment: @mbeckish
Yes i tried. it is not going to my whil loop that means it the quesry is running but it is not giving me any out put on the screen

Comment: And what did you find?  Did the squery variable contain the correct SQL?  What did the reader variable contain after command.ExecuteReader()?

Comment: Well it is not containing anything. I tried the simple select stament before and it was working properly but this one is not workig at all

Comment: The squery variable didn't contain anything?

Comment: not after this query. but i ran another query before at that time it was containing what i wanted.

Comment: squery is a string.  Why didn't it contain the SQL any more after the query is executed?

Comment: Sorry my bad that variable has the value but my reader is not containing anything to read so it is not going in to while loop

Comment: Since this is an inner join and not an outer join, you can try moving the subselect out of the join..on clause and into a WHERE clause after the inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put [CommandText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext.aspx) to [CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype.aspx) and try it.

```
using(SqlConnection sqcon = new SqlConnection(
"Data Source=WMLON-Z8-SQL20,61433;Initial Catalog=statusdb;Integrated Security=True"))
{
   using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(squery,sqcon)){
      command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      sqcon.Open();
      using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while(reader.Read()){
            Console.WriteLine(reader[0]+"\t"+reader[1]);
          }
      }
      sqcon.Close();
   }
} 

-- Using EXISTS or IN could improve your query
    SELECT DISTINCT
            Context.ContextId ,
            ContextName
    FROM    Context
            INNER JOIN RunInstance ON Context.ContextId = RunInstance.ContextId 
            INNER JOIN ProcessInstance ON RunInstance.RunInstanceId = ProcessInstance.RunInstanceId
    WHERE   RiskDate = '2010-08-20'
```

Comment: Where do you want me to put this?

Comment: The name 'CommandType' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: You need to reference System.Data. Add "using System.Data;" to the top of the page.

Comment: Ok.
So I put System.Data.CommandType.Text now. but still it is not showing me anything.

Comment: Everything look ok to me. Let try simple one. Change your query to "SELECT * FROM Context" and try again.

Comment: The simple select statement works perfectly fine. but this is complecated one which is not working.

Comment: Your inner join is a bit strange. Could you look at my updated answer?

Comment: Thanks it was helpful but it is not solving my problem.
i tried to work without date and it works but i need the date because everything is depended on my date.

Comment: Oh, I see. Querying Date field is very specific. You need BETWEEN '2012-07-31' AND '2012-08-01' or CONVERT. http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/2209321/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables-Part-Three---Searching-for-Particular-Date-Values-and-Ranges.htm

Comment: WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(10),RiskDate,120) = '2010-08-20'

Comment: Thanks for your help. It actually worked.
I made some silly mistakes too. but it is working perfectly now.
Thank you again Win for all your help.